# Event needs multiple clicks in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the response from the PHP scripts but the button takes multiple clicks on firing the event. I read about that on Google but unable to understand that why it is going to happen.

**Html Code**

```
<form action="javascript:MyResults()">  
     <input type="submit" value="Search" id ="button1"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function MyResults(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            var searchData = $("#search").val();
            alert(searchData);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/test.php",
                type:"POST",
                async:true,
                data:{
                    "search" : searchDat,
                },
                success: function(value){
                    alert( JSON.parse(value));
                    $.each(value, function(index, value1){
                            console.log(value1);
                    });
                }   
            });
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your current code doesn't set-up the click-handler for button until the form is submitted.  That first click triggers the `action` attribute on the `<form>`, which sets up the handler.  The second click then calls the button handler.

Instead of your current code, you probably want HTML like this:

```
<form>  
     <input type="submit" value="Search" id ="button1"/>
</form>
```

Use `$(document).ready(...)` without the wrapper `function MyResults()`, and be sure to cancel the click event to stop traditional form submission:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var searchData = $("#search").val();
        alert(searchData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/test.php",
            type:"POST",
            async:true,
            data:{
                "search" : searchDat,
            },
            success: function(value){
                alert( JSON.parse(value));
                $.each(value, function(index, value1){
                        console.log(value1);
                });
            }   
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `$(document).ready(function()` inside `MyResult` function . In first case it will execute the `MyFunction` & in second case it will execute the code inside the `ready` function.

Actually there is no need to the `action` here. Following change will work

**HTML**

```
<form id='target'>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" id="button1" />
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#target").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault()
    var searchData = $("#search").val();
    alert(searchData);
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/test.php",
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      data: {
        "search": searchData,
      },
      success: function(value) {
        alert(JSON.parse(value));
        $.each(value, function(index, value1) {
          console.log(value1);
        });
      }
    });
  });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here fired one event at two times.

- First fired when form submit.

  action="javascript:MyResults()"
- Second fired after form submit which you have defined in the function part.

  $("#button1").click(function(){});